# Replacing a repeating number in a file with random numbers

Tags: string, bash, sed

I want to replace all occurrences of a number with a random number in each line of a file using "sed".
For example, if my file has the number 892 in each line, I would like to replace that with a unique random number between 800 and 900.

Input file:-

```
temp11;djaxfile11;892  
temp12;djaxfile11;892  
temp13;djaxfile11;892  
temp14;djaxfile11;892  
temp15;djaxfile11;892
```

Expected output file :-

```
temp11;djaxfile11;805  
temp12;djaxfile11;846  
temp13;djaxfile11;833  
temp14;djaxfile11;881  
temp15;djaxfile11;810
```

I am trying the below:-

```
sed -i -- "s/;892/;`echo $RANDOM % 100 + 800 | bc`/g" file.txt
```

but it is replacing all the occurrences of 892 with a single random number between 800 and 900.

Output file :-

```
temp11;djaxfile11;821  
temp12;djaxfile11;821  
temp13;djaxfile11;821  
temp14;djaxfile11;821  
temp15;djaxfile11;821
```

Could you please help in correcting my code ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Must you absolutely do it in sed? It would be easy in Python or PERL.

Comment: So your file never has more than 101 lines in it, correct? And the number isn't actually random since it is at least partially determined by the previous lines?

Comment: My file actually has thousands of records. The sed suggestion that Wintermute gave is working perfectly, although it is taking a bit of time. Is awk faster from a performance point of view ? any thoughts ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With GNU sed, you could do something like

```
sed '/;892$/ { h; s/.*/echo $((RANDOM % 100 + 800))/e; x; G; s/892\n// }' filename
```

...but it would be much saner to do it with awk:

```
awk -F \; 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $NF == 892 { $NF = int(rand() * 100 + 800) } 1' filename
```

To make sure that the random numbers are unique, amend the awk code as follows:

```
awk -F \; 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $NF == 892 { do { $NF = int(rand() * 100 + 800) } while(!seen[$NF]++) } 1'
```

Doing that with sed would be too crazy for me. **Be aware that this will only work only if there are less than 100 lines with a last field of 892 in the file.**

#### Explanation

The sed code reads

```
/;892$/ {                              # if a line ends with ;892
  h                                    # copy it to the hold buffer
  s/.*/echo $((RANDOM % 100 + 800))/e  # replace the pattern space with the
                                       # output of echo $((...))
                                       # Note: this is a GNU extension
  x                                    # swap pattern space and hold buffer
  G                                    # append the hold buffer to the PS
                                       # the PS now contains line\nrandom number
  s/892\n//                            # remove the old field and the newline
}
```

The awk code is much more straightforward. With `-F \;`, we tell awk to split the lines at semicolons, then

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }  # output field separator is input FS, so the output
                    # is also semicolon-separated
$NF == 892 {        # if the last field is 892
                    # replace it with a random number
  $NF = int(rand() * 100 + 800)
}
1                   # print.
```

The amended awk code replaces

```
$NF = int(rand() * 100 + 800)
```

with

```
do {
  $NF = int(rand() * 100 + 800)
} while(!seen[$NF]++)
```

...in other words, it keeps a table of random numbers it has already used and keeps drawing numbers until it gets one it hasn't seen before.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried the sed code you suggested and it worked fine. I will try out the awk options and explore which is the fastest & best way to do it.

Comment: Answered my own (now deleted) questions:  (1) awk arrays will accept string keys so this should work for string replacements and (2) if you're getting odd behavior and using the `system` call, it may be returning the status code and printing (not returning) the output.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and grep):

```
sed 's/[^0-9]//g;s/8../\n&\n/g' /dev/random |
grep '^8..' |
sed 'R /dev/stdin' file |
sed 'N;s/892\n//;P;d'
```

Use `/dev/random` to produce a stream of random numbers and break out those which have a string of three numbers beginning with `8`.

Grep the lines for the numbers beginning `800` to `899`.

Append a line from the above file to each line of `file`.

If the last 3 characters of the first line begin `892`, remove that number and the following newline (this replaces `892` with a random `800` to `899` number).

Print only the first line of the pair (thus reducing the file to its original  size).